# javascript and html form for dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello i want to create a dynamic input field numbers using html form for Submit and javascript for dynamic input.

in the html form

```
<form action="" method="post" name="detParameterForm">
<fieldset class="det">
<legend>Closure Level</legend>
Number of members:<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value=""><br />
<button id="btn" onclick="addinputFields()">Button</button>
<div id="container"/>
</fieldset>
<button type="submit" value="Submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

in the javascript

```
function addinputFields(){
    var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
    for (i=0;i<number;i++){
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
```

but not work i take error
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fkfowx10/)

Comment: Your JsFiddle doesn't match the question... Can you please explain **"but not work i take error"**

Comment: jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aaki/hMJEy/1/ appears to have different `js` than at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 no i dont want this

Comment: `js` at Question appears to return expected results, when `<` is added to `form` element

Comment: @hellas the jsFiddle you posted doesn't match the source code in your question. Please check your question.

Comment: yes i have problem with fiddle sorry

Comment: Fiddle is working fine too!'

Comment: i update with right fiddle sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

I have added comments into the updated source code, this should work find for you.

**Changes:** *`event.preventDefault();`* and *`parseInt()`* are used.

```js
function addinputFields(){
  // Disable Default Action (Form Posting)
  event.preventDefault(); 
  // parseInt() - The value entered should be a number / integer
    var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("member").value);
    for (i=0;i<number;i++){
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="detParameterForm">
<fieldset class="det">
<legend>Closure Level</legend>
Number of members:<input type="text" id="member" name="member" value=""><br />
<button id="btn" onclick="addinputFields()">Button</button>
<div id="container"/>
</fieldset>
<button type="submit" value="Submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will reply as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

> [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyWPRJ)

Comment: thnx you very much but if copy - paste your code in the fiddle then not work

Comment: @guest271314 since you have mixed my answer with your own. You don't need `event.preventDefault(); ` in your answer because you have a span styled as a button, a span will not trigger the form submit. If you want to try combine my answer with your own at least understand my answer before trying to mix it into your own.

Comment: @hellas run the html file locally. using forms on jsfiddle isn't a good idea.

Comment: @hellas all is working on CodePen  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyWPRJ and runs fine locally.

Comment: @NewToJS _"If you want to try combine my answer with your own at least understand my answer before trying to mix it into your own."_ ? What do you mean by "mix" ?

Comment: @guest271314 You have taken the JS I posted but used your changes to the HTML and CSS from your answer. That would be mixing my answer with your own but it doesn't make sense to have `event.preventDefault();` in the function if the element used to trigger the function isn't going to submit the form.

Comment: @NewToJS This uses `html` from your solution http://jsfiddle.net/hMJEy/1709/ . There reason that function was not called is due to it not being defined before called. Your solution returns expected results

Comment: @guest271314 But why in the jsfiddle you posted are you using a span element styled as a button while having `event.preventDefault();` in the function? If you want to use a span element to trigger the function then you don't need `event.preventDefault();` That's the question I'm asking you. Why have it if it isn't needed... hence me saying *"If you want to try combine my answer with your own at least understand my answer before trying to mix it into your own."*

Comment: OP commented that you solution did not return expected results. Created a jsfiddle to demonstrate that your solution _does_ return expected results. Initial jsfiddle erroneously contained `span` , though this did not intend to indicate that your solution did not return expected results. http://jsfiddle.net/hMJEy/1709/ contains the `html` from your solution and defines `addinputFields` before it is called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104797/discussion-between-newtojs-and-guest271314).

Comment: guest271314 and NewToJS thnx both to help me,one more question if from the new fields inputs i want to take some results (some math functions like sum for example) click on Submit button,can i do that with that script ?

Comment: @hellas Some math functions? Can you create an example please? If you have found a solution can you make one of the answer please.

Comment: my target is to connect javascript inputs(numbers) with a python script on the view.py into the django and i take results from progress

Comment: i find solution thnx for all

Answer (score 0):

first of all , you should get a Container object . And then use the variable container to appendChild evoking . and it can be worked

Comment: i not understand you i am newbie

Answer (score 0):

Clicking a `button` element that is descendant of `form` parent will submit the `form` . Try substituting `span` element for `button` and styling `span` to appear as a `button` to prevent submission of `form` on `click` event

```js
function addinputFields() {
  var number = document.getElementById("member").value;
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
```

```css
form span {
  appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" name="detParameterForm">
  <fieldset class="det">
    <legend>Closure Level</legend>
    Number of members:
    <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value="">
    <br />
    <span id="btn" onclick="addinputFields()">Button</span>
    <div id="container" />
  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But why style something to look like a button when you can use an actual button and event.preventDefault();`? The onclick attribute is only on the `button` not on the submit button...